# Flutter - Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error when interacting with TextField in AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter application where I have a dialog with a TextField. The dialog is shown when a list item is pressed. The dialog has a TextField for user input and two buttons for 'Submit' and 'Cancel'.  However, I am encountering an `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error` when I interact with the TextField in the dialog. The error occurs immediately when I click on the TextField, before any button is pressed.  Here is the relevant code for the dialog:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Manage Categories'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            showEditDialog(null, -1);
          },
          label: Text('Add Category', style: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        body: inProgress
            ? const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center, child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.separated(
                itemCount: categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(categories[index].name,
                        style:
                            GoogleFonts.poppins(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    subtitle: Text('${categories[index].items} items',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
                    trailing: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.edit_outlined),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showEditDialog(categories[index], index);
                          },
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.delete_outlined,
                            color: HexColor('#f64e60'),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            deleteConfirmation(categories[index]);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      if (widget.chooser) {
                        Navigator.pop(context, categories[index]);
                      } else {
                        // Open chooser here
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return const Divider();
                },
              ));
  }

  showEditDialog(Category? category, int index) {
    TextEditingController categoryNameController = TextEditingController();
    if (category != null) {
      categoryNameController.text = category.name;
    }
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('${category != null ? 'Edit' : 'Add'} Category', style: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(child:
          TextField(
            controller: categoryNameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter category name",
                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
          ),),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel', style: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Submit', style: GoogleFonts.poppins()),
              onPressed: () async {
                // Handle the submit action
                if (categoryNameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                  String companyId = context.read<AuthAPI>().company?.$id ?? '';
                  Api api = Api(context.read<AuthAPI>().appwriteClient);
                  if (category != null) {
                    // Update category
                    Category result = await api.updateCategory(
                        category.id, categoryNameController.text);
                    setState(() {
                      SnackBar snackBar = MessageUtil.showSnackBar(
                          MessageType.SUCCESS, 'Category updated successfully');
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      categories[index] = result;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  } else {
                    // Create category
                    Category result = await api.createCategory(categoryNameController.text, companyId);
                    setState(() {
                      SnackBar snackBar = MessageUtil.showSnackBar(
                          MessageType.SUCCESS, 'Category created successfully');
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      categories.add(result);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  SnackBar snackBar = MessageUtil.showSnackBar(
                      MessageType.ERROR, 'Category name cannot be empty');
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

}

I have checked similar questions everyone is talking about expanded widget but I don't really have it anywhere. What is wrong here?

Update : I have edited my question to include build method as well also my flutter version is 3.19.3

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue solely with the `showEditDialog` function. Could you please provide the complete widget code, if possible, and also specify your Flutter SDK version?

Comment: I have edited my question to include more details, please see the updated question.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with the code you provided. Additionally, I'm also using Flutter version 3.19.3. You mentioned showing the dialog on click of the `ListTile`, but the page is being popped on click on the `ListTile`.